# sgx launch control is lockeds,upport sgx virtualization

Tags: ubuntu, sysbios

**After installing Ubuntu** it tells to enable SGX and vitualizatuon, but after doing both I am getting sgx launch control is locked support sgx virtualization.

System: intel celeron @N40000 1.10GHZ